# Why bootloaders for x86 use 16bit code first?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, kernel, bootloader

I read some code of bootloaders for x86. The first part of these bootloaders is usually written using gas. They use ".code16" to tell gas generate 16bit code.

However, I found that 32bit code is executable in REAL MODE. Why do they use 16bit code? Is the ".code16" necessary?

Comment: It doesn't need to use 16-bit code if booting in UEFI mode

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use 32 bit code but you are nevertheless bound by real mode segmentation and BIOS services. `.code16` is however necessary because the cpu is running in 16 bit mode, so to use 32 bit instructions you need to use operand and address-size override prefixes. The directive instructs the assembler to add those for you.

If you write `mov edx, eax` without `.code16`, the assembler will generate machine code `89 C2`. However when the cpu is in 16 bit mode, it will interpret that as `mov dx, ax`. If you really want to operate on 32 bits, you need a `66` prefix, that is `66 89 C2`. Using `.code16` the assembler will do just that. The `66` prefix basically switches to the "other" mode, that is it will use 32 bit when in 16 bit mode and vica versa. This also means if you write `mov dx, ax` in 32 bit code, you will get `66 89 C2`, which when run in 16 bit mode is `mov edx, eax`. So you need to tell the assembler what mode your code is intended to run under.

TL;DR: `.code16` ensures that the assembler generates code which when executed by the cpu in 16 bit mode will do what you intended.

Comment: You should also mention that the large advantage of 32-bit code is non-segmented memory access. In real mode however addressing memory will not work in an unsegmented way; `mov eax,[ebx]` will only work if ebx has a value less than 0x10000.

Comment: Why would that be worth to mentions in this context? The CPU _is_ in 16-bit mode and will decode the machine code as 16-bit, even though the encoding can overridden one instruction at a time. Because the CPU _is_ in 16-bit mode, `.code16` is mandatory for consistency.

Comment: @MartinRosenau that can still work if you take a quick side trip to pmode to set the segment limits to 0xFFFFFFFF (that sticks if you go back to real mode)

Comment: @harold the original question was why the initial boot-up code is written in 16-bit. At this point of time the CPU has not been in protected mode yet.

Comment: @MartinRosenau I did mention "_bound by real mode segmentation_". I didn't feel like that needed any more explanation.

Comment: @Jester Thank you very much. Here is my understanding, and please tell me whether I am right: Actually, 32bit code is not executable in REAL MODE. REAL MODE just adds some extension to 16bit code so that 32bit registers can be used. 16bit code is also not executable in PROTECTED MODE.

Comment: @MartinRosenau that's not the point. Of course the segment limits are not 0xFFFFFFFF *yet* at the beginning of the bootloader, but at any point you can decide to change them, go back to real mode, and work with a flat 32bit address space in 99% of your bootloader. So, non-segmented memory is actually not a large advantage of 32bit code - you only need to execute 3 instructions in pmode ever to unlock that capability.

Comment: @harold that'd be not real mode then. It's rather known as "unreal" or "flat real" mode.

Comment: @Ruslan it's colloquially called that but it's not a distinct mode and regardless of the limits it will always be real mode

Answer (score 1):

Intel:

Instruction prefixes can be used to override the default operand size and address size of a code segment. These prefixes can be used in real-address mode as well as in protected mode and virtual-8086 mode. An operand-size or address-size prefix only changes the size for the duration of the instruction.

The following two instruction prefixes allow mixing of 32-bit and 16-bit operations within one segment:
•The operand-size prefix (66H)
•The address-size prefix (67H)

These prefixes reverse the default size selected by the D flag in the code-segment descriptor. For example, the processor can interpret the (MOV mem, reg) instruction in any of four ways:
•In a 32-bit code segment:
—Moves 32 bits from a 32-bit register to memory using a 32-bit effective address.
—If preceded by an operand-size prefix, moves 16 bits from a 16-bit register to memory using a 32-bit effective address.
—If preceded by an address-size prefix, moves 32 bits from a 32-bit register to memory using a 16-bit effective address.
—If preceded by both an address-size prefix and an operand-size prefix, moves 16 bits from a 16-bit register to memory using a 16-bit effective address.

•In a 16-bit code segment:
—Moves 16 bits from a 16-bit register to memory using a 16-bit effective address.
—If preceded by an operand-size prefix, moves 32 bits from a 32-bit register to memory using a 16-bit effective address.
—If preceded by an address-size prefix, moves 16 bits from a 16-bit register to memory using a 32-bit effective address.
—If preceded by both an address-size prefix and an operand-size prefix, moves 32 bits from a 32-bit register to memory using a 32-bit effective address.

The previous examples show that any instruction can generate any combination of operand size and address size regardless of whether the instruction is in a 16- or 32-bit segment. The choice of the 16- or 32-bit default for a code segment is normally based on the following criteria:
•Performance — Always use 32-bit code segments when possible. They run much faster than 16-bit code segments on P6 family processors, and somewhat faster on earlier IA-32 processors.
•The operating system the code segment will be running on — If the operating system is a 16-bit operating system, it may not support 32-bit program modules.
•Mode of operation — If the code segment is being designed to run in real-address mode, virtual-8086 mode, or SMM, it must be a 16-bit code segment.
•Backward compatibility to earlier IA-32 processors — If a code segment must be able to run on an Intel 8086 or Intel 286 processor, it must be a 16-bit code segment.

The D flag in a code-segment descriptor determines the default operand-size and address-size for the instructions of a code segment. (In real-address mode and virtual-8086 mode, which do not use segment descriptors, the default is 16 bits.) A code segment with its D flag set is a 32-bit segment; a code segment with its D flag clear is a 16-bit segment.

Executable code segment. The flag is called the D flag and it indicates the default length for effective addresses and operands referenced by instructions in the segment. If the flag is set, 32-bit addresses and 32-bit or 8-bit operands are assumed; if it is clear, 16-bit addresses and 16-bit or 8-bit operands are assumed.
The instruction prefix 66H can be used to select an operand size other than the default, and the prefix 67H can be used select an address size other than the default.

The 32-bit operand prefix can be used in real-address mode programs to execute the 32-bit forms of instructions. This prefix also allows real-address mode programs to use the processor’s 32-bit general-purpose registers.
The 32-bit address prefix can be used in real-address mode programs, allowing 32-bit offsets.

The IA-32 processors beginning with the Intel386 processor can generate 32-bit offsets using an address override prefix; however, in real-address mode, the value of a 32-bit offset may not exceed FFFFH without causing an exception.

Assembler Usage:
If a code segment that is going to run in real-address mode is defined, it must be set to a USE 16 attribute. If a 32-bit operand is used in an instruction in this code segment (for example, MOV EAX, EBX), the assembler automatically generates an operand prefix for the instruction that forces the processor to execute a 32-bit operation, even though its default code-segment attribute is 16-bit.

The 32-bit operand prefix allows a real-address mode program to use the 32-bit general-purpose registers (EAX, EBX, ECX, EDX, ESP, EBP, ESI, and EDI).

When moving data in 32-bit mode between a segment register and a 32-bit general-purpose
register, the Pentium Pro processor does not require the use of a 16-bit operand size prefix;
however, some assemblers do require this prefix. The processor assumes that the 16 least-significant
bits of the general-purpose register are the destination or source operand. When moving a
value from a segment selector to a 32-bit register, the processor fills the two high-order bytes of
the register with zeros.

Comment: Quoting reference documentation is certainly useful but right now it is quite long with **no TL;DR**, consider using http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting to make it more readable

Answer (score 0):

When the first Intel processors were made they all used 16 bit code, 32 bit wasn't used. When the 386 processor was produced as 32 bits, Intel specified that it's default start state would be 16 bits for backward compatibility with the older processors. The OS or Bootloader developer could then use 16 bit instructions to access Protected (32 bit) Mode. Intel seem to like their backward compatibility and this has stuck on all x86 processors to date so they can retain compatibility with older software.